# Compare distance of element from click event using closest()

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, element, closest

I have various elements that fire the same function. I need to be able to get the closet element of two different types of classes.

Before I would just have a function for each onClick event, though I want them to share the same one and instead just change the current_dragging_element to which ever element was closest to the two types of classes I am looking for.

```
current_dragging_element = event.target.closest(".draggable_list");
current_dragging_element = event.target.closest(".draggable_item");
```

```
async function onMouseDown(event) {
    
    if (HANDLE THE CHANGE IN VAR?) {
      current_dragging_element = event.target.closest(".draggable_list");
      
    }
    else {
      current_dragging_element = event.target.closest(".draggable_item");
    }
    document.body.classList.add("noselect")
    current_dragging_element.style.transform = "rotate(5deg)";
    current_dragging_element.style.left = event.clientX - 20
    current_dragging_element.style.top = event.clientY - 20
    current_dragging_element.classList.add("drag");
    current_dragging_element.style.position = "fixed";
    current_dragging_element.style.zIndex = 999;

  }
```

This is what I have far, however it doesn't function correctly yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Need to start by explaining what your interpretation of *"closest"* means. `Element.closest()` is for ancestors only. Also please provide a `[mcve] and a more detailed explanation of the expected behavior

Comment: Good point. 

I need the closest element to the mouse click location. 

I think I might have figured it out. I am getting the cords of the event.click location and then compare it to the location of the elements im trying to find. And then see which has the shortest distance. If that makes sense. If I get it to work I will post it.

Comment: There are numerous drag/drop libraries that may simplify what you are trying to accomplish. Using only mouse coordinates may not do enough for you s it's possible for mouse to be closer to one container but the bounds of the dragged element be closer to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element.closest()` works like a CSS selector, just like `querySelector()`. You can add multiple classes in a single string and get the first encounter of one of those elements.

See example below.

```js
const entries = document.querySelectorAll('.entry');
entries.forEach(entry => {
  const closest = entry.closest('.draggable_list, .draggable_item');
  console.log(closest);
});
```

```html
<!-- draggable item is the closest -->
<div class="draggable_list">
  <div class="draggable_item">
    <div class="entry"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- draggable list is the closest -->
<div class="draggable_list">
  <div class="entry"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect sir. Much simpler than the approach I was just working on, which required a heap of math lol.

Comment: Do note that it does not calculate the actual "closest element in pixel distance", but the closest element moving up the DOM tree. It's not yet clear which one you were looking for.